# Sql Sync causing source server to run out of memory causing error during sync to client server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework, failover

I am synching my production SQL Server 2008 R2 db with my failover SQL Server 2008 R2 Express server using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 and it worked great for a while and then after a few days of syncs the source (production SQL Server) **starts running out of memory** (RAM) because of the syncs.

It didn't stop running or anything or cause website transactions to fail but the **Sync Framework** starts throwing the below error if there is low ram on production box.

Anyone seen this or have any idea why it is doing this and if there is a fix?

Here is the error ..

> Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncException: An unexpected exception occurred in a   background thread that is enumerating
>   changes. See the inner exception for more details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is insufficient system
>   memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.DeriveParameters()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(SqlCommand
>   command)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ManagementUtils.DeriveParameters(SqlCommand
>   command, IEnumerable`1 columns)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncAdapter.SetCommandSessionParameters(IDbCommand
>   command, String commandName)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.EnumerateChangesInBatchesInternal(Object
>   batchProducer)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchProducer.DequeueBatch()
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.ConsumeBatchFromProducer(DbSyncScopeMetadata
>   scopeMetadata)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.GetChanges(DbSyncScopeMetadata
>   scopeMetadata, DbSyncSession DbSyncSession, UInt32 memoryBatchSize)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.GetChangeBatch(UInt32
>   batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge, Object&
>   changeDataRetriever)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeProviderProxy.GetChangeBatch(UInt32
>   dwBatchSize, ISyncKnowledge pSyncKnowledge, ISyncChangeBatch&
>   ppChangeBatch, Object& ppUnkDataRetriever)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.CoreInterop.ISyncSession.Start(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION_POLICY
>   resolutionPolicy, _SYNC_SESSION_STATISTICS& pSyncSessionStatistics)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWaySyncHelper(SyncIdFormatGroup
>   sourceIdFormats, SyncIdFormatGroup destinationIdFormats, 
>   KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration destinationConfiguration,
>   SyncCallbacks DestinationCallbacks, ISyncProvider sourceProxy,
>   ISyncProvider destinationProxy, ChangeDataAdapter
>   callbackChangeDataAdapter, SyncDataConverter conflictDataConverter,
>   Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWayKnowledgeSync(SyncDataConverter
>   sourceConverter, SyncDataConverter destinationConverter, SyncProvider
>   sourceProvider, SyncProvider destinationProvider, Int32&
>   changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()

Comment: Note : If I restart the production SQL box it starts working again. But I want to know why it happens and if there is a fix (patch wise or settings wise)

Answer (score 1):

try enabling batching by setting the MemoryDataCacheSize property.

Comment: I think I did but I will check later

Comment: I do this already uint memoryDataCacheSize = 524288; _SyncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scope, ClientConn) { MemoryDataCacheSize = memoryDataCacheSize };
                    // set the main sql provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
                    // the scope in the main server database
                    _SyncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scope, ServerConn) { MemoryDataCacheSize = memoryDataCacheSize };

Comment: and how much memory do you have on your SQL Server box and what's the setting for SQL Server's Max memory? how big is your database and how much data are you actually synching?

Comment: 4G RAM. Max memory is :2147483647 MB (The default). DB size = Data file - 492MB, Log file = 14.1 GB. As far as how much data am I actually synching...I am only syncing tables with changing data, not static tables that never change. My syncs only take 5-20 sec every 30 min. Initial sync took like 15-20 min.